# How to setup Core Data model for simple to-do list app?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Please teach me how to setup a Core Data model for a simple to-do list app.

I know how to make simple `UITableView` with datasource from `CoreData`, but I don't understand what I should do if I have two `TableViews`:
[Look at the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H2b9.png)

First `[TableView]` contains folders, but second `[TableView]` contains to-do lists. The list should be different for each folders.

How to create such Core Data model and how to fetch to-do list result for every selected folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you create two Data model, one for folders, another one for todo.

In folders model, set relationship to todo-model (one-to-many, inverse-able, delete rule: cascade)

Using `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch record from SQlite, it will be like this:

```
let fetchRequset = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Folder")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
fetchRequset.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequset, managedObjectContext: managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
do {
    try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

populate result of `NSFetchedResultsController` for your tableView

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return (self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count)!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("folderTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FolderTableViewCell

    let folder = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Folder
    cell.folder = folder

    return cell
}
```

Fot todo tableView, you only have to pass the object in NSFetchedResultsController result when perform segue:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedFolder = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Folder
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("todoView", sender: self)
}
```

All coreData operation such as delete, create, modify .. you need to use NSManagedObjectContext. Since you already have the basic knowledge about it, i will leave it to you

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Also for me was a question how to add keep an array of objects (to-do lists) in the Core Data, I found that I should use many-to-many relationship. Now it works.